# Question to "Start-up into resistive load" diagram of LTC3106

Tags: load, resistive

There is a diagram on page 7 of the LTC3106 ([Datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3106f.pdf)) named "Start-up into resistive load" and i couldn't find any explanation on the internet how to understand it.

My assumption is: 
This diagram shows what load is allowed at the output of the ltc3106 for a given Vin at start-up without getting any problems. 
So this means: if i have 100Ohms load, the ltc might get problems at start-up with 3V Vin.

Is this right?

Comment: I would imagine it means what you say.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct.   This chart describes the minimum resistance, using a 10uH Inductor, that will allow the converter to startup.  Otherwise it will not start or go into a protection mode.

Many microcontroller and system on a chip semiconductor loads are not resistive in nature and only start to draw significant current after they reach a certain voltage and go through a startup sequence.  If your load is a microcontroller or processor then you can adjust this startup time to allow the converter to start.

Comment: Indeed, with 10uH and 100mA load at least 4.5V are required. I tested 30uH and now 4.1V is ok. Any links/literature how to calculate the inductor value that is needed for about 3.5V startup? Testing different values seems not to be the best option

Comment: As you have found, the larger inductor will reduce the peak and value ripple current of the boost/buck converter allowing you to adjust the values shown in the table a little.  However, I would not think it would change much from your experiments and I would not recommend for high volume applications.     Which application diagram fits your use the best?

Comment: Sry, but I don't understand your answer. Can you explain it once again?